# html and php code spacing

Tags: php, html, htmltidy

is there any proper application, tools or other way to clean-up a codes which messed with blocking-space.

i have this experience with my fellow developer after she save the document (html & php) then synchronize to my end, it was messy with horrible block-spacing something like this in my link.

```
<?php some code here


and code/tags here,


and additional content lines here...


closing


?>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/DJwJe/)

Comment: What do you use for code editing? Every IDE that I know of, has a "format source" option which sets indentation and other white space according to definable rules.

Comment: we do use 3 types of editors, Sublime Text 2 (win) (I and my fellow-developer use it), Dreamweaver (win) and Coda 2 (osx). Someone told me that it occurs when it was uploading to server. my friend use SFTP from Sublime Text 2, while me and the other use CuteFTP.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like these?

Web:
http://beta.phpformatter.com/

Coda:
http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/software/coda-php/